# searching and replacing words with upper and lower cases of the same word

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

The point of this script is to replace multiple strings of words despite if the word starts with a lower case letter or upper case letter.

code example:

```
import re
from re import sub

def word_replace(text, replace_dict):
    rc = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z_]\w*")
def translate(match):
    word = match.group(0) 
    return replace_dict.get(word, word)
return rc.sub(translate, text)

old_text = """Bob: say why don't you play ball
jeff: i have no idea
bob: well maybe you should """

replace_dict = {
"Bob" : 'bob baller',
"debug" : "fix",
'ship': 'boat'
 }
```

what i get is:

```
bob baller: say why don't you play ball
jeff: i have no idea
bob: well maybe you should
```

what i would like to get out of the text is both "Bob" and "bob" then replace them both with bob baller.

To clear up the question a little bit more, what i am trying to do is replace the word 'bob' (or any-word in replace_dict) if it's upper-case or lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Compile your regex with additional argument like this</strike>

<strike>re.compile("your regex goes here", re.IGNORECASE)</strike>

**Edit 1:**

Okay so it turns out that your replace_dict is not formed correctly due to inconsistent usage of double and single quotes.
Here is the working code and expected output:

## bob_baller.py

```
import re

def word_replace(text, replace_dict):
    rc = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z_]\w*")

    def translate(match):
        word = match.group(0).lower()
        print(word)
        return replace_dict.get(word, word)

    return rc.sub(translate, text)

old_text = """Bob: say why don't you play ball
jeff: i have no idea
bob: well maybe you should """

replace_dict = {
    "bob" : "bob baller",    # Everything is double quoted
    "debug" : "fix",
    "ship": "boat"
 }

output = word_replace(old_text, replace_dict)
print(output)

$ python bob_baller.py
bob baller: say why don't you play ball
jeff: i have no idea
bob baller: well maybe you should
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your replace_dict keys to lowercase and then match for both words and replace. like match for Bob and bob too.

Comment: i was thinking something along those lines, but (this is actually my fault for not putting it in my original posting) i was going to use this code for looking at much larger text areas (old_text) and using a ton of words in my replace_dic, trying to taking the tediousness out of the process of entering in all upper, lower, prefixes, and suffixes. anyways thank you for your answer worst comes to worst i'll be using this.

Comment: You can write lke this   re.compile(r"[A-Za-z_]\w*", re.I). It will ignore case